# Ask Wizard cards could have colors coordinated with focused field

Tags: feature-request, design, ask-question-wizard

This is how Ask Wizard highlighting looks now (Stack Overflow, dark theme). Notice how the blue frame around this text area is the same color as background of the big box at the top, even though there is also a tip in a card to the right

[image: screenshot of how Ask Wizard experience looks now]

What if instead, it looked like the following. When a text field or area is focused and thus highlighted, the corresponding advice to the right could have coordinated color.

[image: screenshot of how Ask Wizard experience could look like]

Of course, this suggestion is not exclusive to dark mode. Light mode could have color coordination too:

[image: example of suggestion in light mode]